# Whirlpool dishwasher: can't set program and just says "Out"

Tags: appliances, dishwasher

My whirlpool dishwasher (ADG 8410 FD) won't allow me to set a program. The display just says "Out", and when I close it, you can hear the drain pump for about a minute and then it stops and beeps a couple of times.

My first thought was that "out" meant outlet. So I disconnected the pipe and poured water into the dishwasher base so the filter area was full. Turned it on and all that water drained without issue (leaving a very small puddle at the bottom).

There's nothing in the manual that says about this "out" message. Nothing online. Any ideas? There is no F error. Turning off/on at the plug does nothing - as soon as the dishwasher is turned on it shows "Out" on the display.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Did you figure it out by now? You can answer your own question and thus help others having the same problem in the future.

Comment: I'm ashamed to say it was entirely user error. Will add an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was completely and utterly user error.

For anyone else having the same problem, press the play key and not the cross to turn the thing on! The cross runs an outlet cycle, the play allows you to set a program. Doh.

Answer (score 1):

Possible (probable in my limited experience) problem : the wires are corroded.

Take off the panel and inspect the cable (likely green with flat copper strands). If it's corroded, gently clean it with a magic eraser, or harsher methods if necessary.  Then coat it with liquid electrical tape.  Finally, inspect the seal around the door - it can be knocked off-kilter pretty easily, and just needs to be set back in place.

As I said my exp is limited, but with my dishwasher and range microwave, this has been the problem when display was snafu'ed.

If a noticeable amount of steam leaked from the top of your dishwasher in recent months, this is almost definitely the problem.

There should be some videos on how to remove the panel if you want a step by step.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Did you have the same issue? I'm a bit reluctant to remove the panel (and potentially cause more issues by seals breaking) if it's not the problem.  Perhaps I should have elaborated - the display is working, it just says "Out" when turned on, then trying to set a program (or press anything other than off) flashes "--:--" 3 times, and returns to "Out".  So I'm not sure this is a broken display?

Comment: I did have the same issue. There's no worry about seals breaking. The back of the display panel is screwed on and sealed via gasket. While it's technically air tight, the steam inside the dishwasher creates enough pressure to push a tiny bit through. Over time, this can cause corrosion. -- I'm not 100% that this is your problem, but I'm sure that it's the first thing you should check. When mine had this issue and I googled/youtubed  around, this was the most probable cause I read about and turned out to be the culprit.

Comment: If you want a step by step, there is almost certainly a video on youtube or vimeo that shows a pro taking off the panel. Search for your make and model and something should come up.

Comment: Finally got round to checking and all the wiring seems good around the circuit board... looks good as new, no corrosion. Thanks anyway!